# How can I link one face data to multiple faces for uv mapping?

Tags: texturing, uv

I am trying to UV map a tire. It has multiple spokes but all spokes instead of being separate objects are joined with join tool to form a single object. And I am wondering if I can copy one data of spoke to  all the spokes?

CTRL+L copies the data in the object mode but since all the spokes are part of an object, I want to copy one spoke data to all the spokes in edit mode. Or is there any other way?

[image: rim in object mode] [image: rim in edit mode]

Thanks!

Comment: If they're all the same object then they already have all the same data.

Comment: @RayMairlot actually they are not the same object. Think as you are designing a house which has same size windows. One window is made and just duplicated(no linking) and then all the windows are joined. Now when I am in UV editing and I apply texture to a window, I want to link all windows to that original window. But I can't do so because it is an object not multiple objects. So how can I link in edit mode?

Comment: You said 'all the windows are joined', which means they're all part of the same object. I think you should use the [edit] button under the question to add this additional information and preferably some pictures to explain what you have and what you want.

Comment: as you can see is that each spoke is an individual entity but all are a part of an object. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Quick answer:** No, as far as I know there is no way to copy UV data between chunks of mesh belonging to the same object.

If the spokes are all the same they should be kept as separate objects, as instances sharing the same object data.

Anyway if you still want them as one object then

1. Select your spokes object
2. Enter edit mode
3. Select one spoke
4. Separate it from the main object using <kbd>P</kbd>
5. Exit edit mode and enter edit mode on your separate spoke object
6. Edit it as desired, and assign it the correct UV coordinates.
7. Now place the 3D cursor at the center of the wheel/spokes
8. Press <kbd>.</kbd> (Period key) to rotate around the 3D cursor
9. Copy your spoke object with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to make instances
10. Press <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate around the 3D cursor
11. Adjust the angle as desired and place as many copies as necessary

You may now join them again as before, and they will all have the same UV coordinates, although I think there are better workflows.

Either keep them as separate object instances sharing the same object data and that will keep them in sync automatically, or alternatively, if you need them as a single object, use an *Array Modifier*.

1. Delete all but one instance, and add an *Array Modifier* to the
   remaining one. Set it to object offset.
2. Now with the 3D cursor still in the center of the tire add a new
   empty object
3. Rotate it the same amount of degrees you would rotate one of the spokes.
4. Assign this empty as object offset to the array modifier
5. Adjust the number of items as desired.

Now you have a single object but they all share UV data and are kept in sync.

[image]